# How do I deploy two Flask applications to the same server on the same subdomain?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I have two Flask applications that are basically independent of each other. Each of them is packaged in its own Docker (using docker-compose). But I need these two applications to be on the same subdomain (you can have them on different ports or in different subdirectories like sub.domain.com/1 and sub.domain.com/2). How to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can create subdomain as shown in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.

Comment: I need to have two sites on one subdomain because I want to use common cookies for both o them.